# Fetch the filtered data and again filter the data in Coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I am working on core data. I have an entity "Catalog", which have 20 attributes more or less. I am fetching the data and used predicate against catalogId which is the attribute in the entity. In received data all entity data but there is repeated data, I have to avoid them. I also used this

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(CategoriesAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest* fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tbl_catalogPage"];
NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tbl_catalogPage"inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetch setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"catalogid == '%@'", catalogId]];
[fetch setPredicate:predicate];
[fetch setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[entity attributesByName]objectForKey:@"pageid"], [[entity attributesByName]objectForKey:@"catalogid"], nil]];
[fetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetch setReturnsDistinctResults : YES];
NSError* error = nil;
self.resultPageArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
NSLog(@"result array count %lu",(unsigned long)self.resultPageArray.count);
NSLog (@"names: %@",self.resultPageArray);
NSLog(@"result array values ");

return resultPageArray;
```

But it didn't work. In Catalog entity, there is an attribute pageId, which is repeating in the whole entity. I want the data using catalogId in which a row having the same pageId should skip, I mean avoid duplication of pageId in fetched data..
Thanks in advance

Comment: `returnsDistinctResults` is only working, if `propertiesToFetch` is set and `resultType` is `NSDictionaryResultType`. However, having repeating IDs is a smell that your model is not normalized. Can you add the complete fetch code and a description of your model to your Q, please.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @Aly As I understand it, your data might include several objects with the same `pageId`, and you want to select only one object for each `pageId`.  The question is, how do you decide which one of those several objects you want to use?

Comment: @pbasdf You do not have to decide that, because uniquing only works, if *all* fetched properties are equal.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I think that's the problem - `returnsDistinctResults` on (pageId, categoryId) will give ALL values of categoryId for each pageId - as I understand it (@Aly correct me if I'm wrong) he wants only ONE value of categoryId for each pageId.

Comment: @Aly please, add an example to your Q, which contains the data set and the desired result set. Do you know that only records with complete equal properties are unified?

Comment: @pbasdf I'm pretty unsure what he expects. He should add examples. However, his model seems to be strange.

Comment: @pbasdf yes exactly you are right, I want only one value of categoryId for each pageId. and in my code i don't know why setReturnsDistinctResults is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses a two-step process.  The reason for using two fetches is this: to select only one object for each `pageid`, we must use `propertiesToGroupBy`, which a) means we must use `NSDictionaryResultType` and b) means we cannot fetch any attributes other than those specified in the `propertiesToGroupBy` (as you found in one of your previous questions).  The two steps are:

1. Fetch NSManagedObjectIDs, grouped by `pageid`.  (Although you can't specify other *attributes*, you can specify the *objectID*.  Note that CoreData will *arbitrarily* pick one object with each `pageid`, and use its objectID.)
2. Fetch the NSManagedObjects with the objectIDs returned by (1).

Code for the above:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(CategoriesAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate managedObjectContext];
// First fetch
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tbl_catalogPage"];
// fetch only object IDs
NSExpressionDescription *objIdED = [NSExpressionDescription new];
objIdED.expression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
objIdED.name = @"objId";
objIdED.expressionResultType = NSObjectIDAttributeType;
[fetch setPropertiesToFetch:@[objIdED]];
// Group by "pageid"
[fetch setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"pageid"]];
// Dictionary result type required for Group By:
[fetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray *interimResults = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
// Convert the array of dictionaries into an array of NSManagedObjectIDs
NSArray *requiredObjectIDs = [interimResults valueForKey:@"objId"];
// Second fetch
NSFetchRequest *secondFetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tbl_catalogPage"];
// Fetch only the objects with the required objectIDs
secondFetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", requiredObjectIDs];
self.resultPageArray = [context executeFetchRequest:secondFetch error:&error];
NSLog(@"result array count %lu",(unsigned long)self.resultPageArray.count);
NSLog (@"names: %@",self.resultPageArray);
NSLog(@"result array values ");
```

(Error checking omitted for brevity).